# Abstract Algebra: Solving Equations with Binary Operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a set, S=Reals{-1} and defined by the operation * by: a*b=a+b+ab; So how would I find the solution of 2*x*3=7?

Comment: First, do you know that the operation is associative? That much is required before you can state $a\ast b \ast c$ without parentheses.

Comment: It's a commutative group. Try to find the neutral element and the inverse of an element. Then use commutativity and associativity to combine the $2$ and the $3$ and then compose by the inverse of $2*3$.

Answer (score 1):

Since both addition and multiplication are commutative, this new operation would be also. $2*3 = 2+3 + 2\times3 = 5+6 = 11$. Therefore, $11*x = 7$. $$11+x+11x = 7$$
$$12x = 11-7$$
$$12x = -4$$
$$x = -1/3$$